# Count how many months had a certain number of orders per location

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table showing year, month, dollar amount, and sales district. Each row is an individual order. I am attempting to write a formula to show how many months did a certain sales district have a certain number of orders. Below is the original table.

[image: Top portion of original table]

The sales district capitol has two rows in this table under January 2015, which means it had two orders total in January. The sales district capitol also has three rows under February 2015, meaning it had three orders total in February.

I'm looking for a way to count this into the following table:

[image: Counted table]

As you can see, the sales district capitol has 1 month under 2 orders and 1 month under 3 orders.

I apologize for the amateurish question, I am not too familiar with excel. I've been trying to use a countifs function on this for about 30 minutes and I just can't crack it. Thank you for help.

Comment: Are you only looking to search under year 2015? Cause as of now, your table to write in doesn't look like it makes a difference for year variables? Also, what if the Total Dollar amount column value shows zero? Would that count? Just a small sidenote too, you seem to have a lot of questions currently unanswered about seemingly the same subject. Not directly a bad thing since they not duplicates but maybe consider to try and close these before you procede with other workarounds etc. They will loose their relevance and start to become loose ends on this website.

Comment: Consider using pivot tables.

Comment: Lets say the two rows listed for Capitol under January 2015 weren't there. Then Capitol would have had 0 orders for January 2015, and that would've been added to the count 0 orders in the second table picture that I posted.

Comment: I am not familiar with pivot tables by any means but I'll look into them

Comment: Try using an if with a countif, something like, =if(countif(SalesDistrict, District) = 1;1;0).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z1Jp5fw-kJjfzfzvxSx7Ki0VvfKnGGP04MSl3D3Sopg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't think this works? Or I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the entire dataset by hitting `CTRL + A`
2. Under the  `Insert` tab select `Pivot Table`
3. Once the Field List Appears, you will see the column headers in the top box and the four boxes on the bottom.
4. Drag `Sales District` in the bottom left box (I can't see your images so I'm doing these blind)
5. Drag `Year` into the top right box, then drag `Month` in the same box (top right) below Year.
6. Drag `Orders` into the bottom right
7. Click the Sum of Orders (or however it appears depending on your data), then click `Value Field Settings`.
8. From the sound of it you want `Count`

This should give you by district the count of sales orders by month by year. From here you can go into the `Design` tab (as long as the table is selected) and adjust colors and banded rows and all that fancy stuff. If you want to see the Sales $, just drag that in. If you don't like the layout, pivot tables are forgiving enough to let you drag the year and month down to the bottom left, and sales district to the top right to see if you want the information differently.

There 5 components to the pivot table you should know.
1. The fields, this is the columns of data
2. The filters, this is the top left box, this is where you can filter stuff out, say you want to look at 1 particular district you can do that there.
3. The rows, this is what appears down the side of the table
4. The columns, this is what goes across the top
5. The Values this is what the table actually shows, the numbers.